# Binding an OBJECT ARRAY to <ul> in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am populating a dropdownbutton from a array. The whole key value pair is being shown as you see in the picture.

1) I need to show only the value of Label.

2)  I want to have "ALL LOCATIONS" as a default item.

[image]

Here is how the Locations look like :

```
Locations:Array[2]
0:Object
$$hashKey:"object:772"
Id:1600
Label:"California"
__proto__:Object
1:Object
$$hashKey:"object:773"
Id:1600
Label:"Atlanta"
__proto__:Object
```

HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toolbar btn-margin-left" style="float: right;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            ALL LOCATIONS {{selectedItem}}
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li ng-repeat="Label in Summary.Locations">
                                <a ng-click="dropboxitemselected(Label)">
                                    {{Label}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>
```

js :

```
WotcDashBoardModuleService.GetDashBoardSummary(Ein).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Summary = response.data.WotcSummary;

        $scope.selectedItem;
        $scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {

            $scope.selectedItem = item;
            //alert($scope.selectedItem);
        }
        console.log($scope.Summary);
    });
```

Comment: He said "I need to show only the value of Label" and then showed he's seeing the entire object.

Comment: Just for information, it looks like you're willing to use <select>. Here's the syntax of the select if you need it...
`<select ng-options="location as location.label for location in locations" ng-model="selectedLocation">
      <option value="">All Locations</option>
    </select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary.Locations is your array of objects, so `Label` gets bound to each element individually.  That means you need to show `{{Label.Label}}` instead of just `{{Label}}` and you'll see the name.

Comment: both are correct answers for the two questions I asked. I would like to select both as answers but only one is allowed!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
ALL LOCATIONS {{selectedItem}}
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<span ng-if="!selectedItem">ALL LOCATIONS</span>
<span ng-if="selectedItem" ng-bind="selectedItem.Label"></span>
```

Or with:

```
<span>{{ selectedItem ? selectedItem.Label : 'ALL LOCATIONS' }}</span>
```